# Equation of an egg figure created by intersecting a torus with a plane

Tags: geometry

I obtained following figure similar to an egg form (in yellow) by intersection of a plane and a torus. I would like have the equation of this "new" geometric form as a function of

- torus radius
- the position of the axis point in the $x$ direction, and
- the angle with respect x.

It would be useful in calculus of magnetic field.

In the image, the torus' major and minor radii are $40$mm and $10$mm at $xy$-plane, and the cutting plane cuts the torus from inner face tangent to $80^\circ$ with respect the $x$-axis:

[image]

Comment: The intersection between a torus and a plane is a [Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, any "new" curve that you discover is known since the XVIIth century.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\, S = \sin(80^ \circ),\, C = \cos(80^ \circ), \,$
$\, r_1+r_2 \,$ be the major radius, and $\, r_1-r_2 \,$ be the minor radius. Then
$$z = \sqrt{ 2  r_1 \sqrt{\,(t S)^2 \!+\! (t C
 \!+\! (r_1\!-\!r_2))^2} - t^2
 \!-\! 2 (r_1\!-\!r_2) (r_1 \!+\! t C)}
\,$$
is the function which comes from the equation of the torus
$$ r_2^2 =  (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - r_1)^2 +  (z-0)^2 $$
where $$ x = r_1-r_2 + t\, C ,\quad y = 0 + t\, S .$$

If a different plane were used the formula must be adjusted.

Comment: I corrected in the post the major radius 50->40mm. I made an excel table with your formula, but unfortunately zmax=57.58770483 that is over 10mm real values. YOU SHOULD DIVIDE z by S. I have uploaded the excel here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ozj32ToCtMBs8oL_ztV3fWyF2UZuYI3icjS7Wkef9NI/edit#gid=1679158538

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Somos I found the response:

$$z=\sqrt{2r1\sqrt{(tS)^{2}+(tC+(r1-r2))^{2} }-t^{2} -2(r1-r2)(r1+tC)}$$

Where:

- r1=major radius (40 in the figure)
- r2=minor radius (10),
- t= x starting at the left of the "egg"
- C=cosine of the cutting plane cos(80º)
- S=sine

Here is the final excel table with the formula:
[Cassini Oval](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17WCEDeZ6L8h1VoYpaJNcPAEeWFutGhq-on1K8C-vZiA)